# Overflow Error in Excel VBA with Type Double

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into an overflow error in Excel VBA and cannot find my way around it. While Microsoft's documentation indicates that the range for doubles should reach ~1.8E308, I am receiving an overflow error for numbers significantly lower than that threshold. My code is as follows:

```
Public Function Fixed_Sample_Nums(ByVal n As Long, seed As Long) As Double()

    Dim x() As Double, y() As Double, i As Long
    ReDim y(1 To n)
    ReDim x(1 To n)

    x(1) = (CDbl(48271) * seed) Mod CDbl(2 ^ 31 - 1)

    For i = 2 To n
        x(i) = (CDbl(48271) * CDbl(x(i - 1))) Mod (CDbl(2 ^ 31 - 1))
        y(i) = CDbl(x(i)) / CDbl(2 ^ 31 - 1)
    Next i

    Fixed_Sample_Nums = y

End Function

'I receive the error in the first iteration of the for loop with 
'seed equal to any value >= 1 (i.e. w/ seed = 1): 

Debug.Print((CDbl(48271) * CDbl(48271)) Mod (CDbl(2 ^ 31 - 1))) 

'results in an overflow error
```

I am attempting to create a pseudo-random number generator that can take in any 'seed' value up to and including 2 ^ 31 - 1. The for loop should be able to iterate at least 9,999 times (i.e. n = 10000). If the overflow error is not encountered within the first few iterations, it most likely will not be encountered for any subsequent iteration.

As you can see, I am converting each integer to a double before any calculation. I am aware of the fact that arrays substantially increase the byte size of the calculation, but that does not appear to be the current issue as I directly copied the example calculation above into the immediate window and still received the overflow error. My attempts to find a solution online have resulted in no avail, so I would really appreciate any input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 42. Mod  2. ^ 31  also crashed, unlike 42. Mod  (2. ^ 31 -1)  ... maybe an undocumented (google gave nothing) feebleness of mod. Who uses that anyway? O.O

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ModFunction.aspx

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for the link! Funny thing is, I've already tried creating my own function, still results in an overflow error. Also, the pseudo-random number generator works in worksheet form with no overflow, but I need to create a VBA function for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Chip Pearson's `XMod` function:

```
x(i) = XMod((CDbl(48271) * seed), CDbl(2 ^ 31 - 1))
```

As he notes:

> You can also get overflow errors in VBA using the Mod operator with
>   very large numbers. For example,
>
> ```
> Dim Number As Double
> Dim Divisor As Double
> Dim Result As Double
>
> Number = 2 ^ 31
> Divisor = 7
> Result = Number Mod Divisor ' Overflow error here.
> ```

Code for the function:

```
Function XMod(ByVal Number As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double) As Double
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' XMod
' Performs the same function as Mod but will not overflow
' with very large numbers. Both Mod and integer division ( \ )
' will overflow with very large numbers. XMod will not.
' Existing code like:
'       Result = Number Mod Divisor
' should be changed to:
'       Result = XMod(Number, Divisor)
' Input values that are not integers are truncated to integers. Negative
' numbers are converted to postive numbers.
' This can be used in VBA code and can be called directly from 
' a worksheet cell.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Number = Int(Abs(Number))
    Divisor = Int(Abs(Divisor))
    XMod = Number - (Int(Number / Divisor) * Divisor)
End Function
```

Additional details:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ModFunction.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! I had tried creating then using a similar function and still received the overflow error. Now I've copied and pasted Pearson's.. Still receiving an overflow error.

Comment: Wow, nvm.. In my initial attempt after creating Pearson's function, I was converting to longs and not doubles x). The PRNG function now works  syntatically and semantically. Thank you!